# Spring boot error: Spring table doesn't exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

when I'm trying to save roles in the database, the "springit.role table doesn't exist" occur.

I'm not creating a table with name "role" in my database because the teacher in the course which I'm learning now didn't create one.

The exception shown when I call the "addUsersAndRoles()" in the DatabaseLoader class method

So, what is the problem?

Role.java

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String password;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void addRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        roles.forEach(this::addRole);
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

DatabaseLoader.java

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private LinkRepository linkRepository;
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public DatabaseLoader(LinkRepository linkRepository, CommentRepository commentRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.linkRepository = linkRepository;
        this.commentRepository = commentRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        addUsersAndRoles();

        Map<String,String> links = new HashMap<>();
        links.put("Securing Spring Boot APIs and SPAs with OAuth 2.0","https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-apis-and-spas-with-oauth2/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=sc&utm_campaign=springboot_spa_securing");
        links.put("Easy way to detect Device in Java Web Application using Spring Mobile - Source code to download from GitHub","https://www.opencodez.com/java/device-detection-using-spring-mobile.htm");
        links.put("Tutorial series about building microservices with SpringBoot (with Netflix OSS)","https://medium.com/@marcus.eisele/implementing-a-microservice-architecture-with-spring-boot-intro-cdb6ad16806c");

        links.forEach((k,v) -> {
            linkRepository.save(new Link(k,v));
            // we will do something with comments later
        });

        long linkCount = linkRepository.count();
        System.out.println("Number of links in the database: " + linkCount );
    }

      private void addUsersAndRoles() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String secret = "{bcrypt}" + encoder.encode("password");

        Role userRole = new Role("ROLE_USER");
        roleRepository.save(userRole);
        Role adminRole = new Role("ROLE_ADMIN");
        roleRepository.save(adminRole);

        User user = new User("user@gmail.com",secret,true);
        user.addRole(userRole);
        userRepository.save(user);

        User admin = new User("admin@gmail.com",secret,true);
        admin.addRole(adminRole);
        userRepository.save(admin);

        User master = new User("master@gmail.com",secret,true);
        master.addRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole,adminRole)));
        userRepository.save(master);

    }

}
```

schema.sql

```
 CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `springit`;
USE `springit`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;

CREATE TABLE `comment` (
                           `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                           `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `body` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `link_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                           KEY `FKoutxw6g1ndh1t6282y0fwvami` (`link_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`;
CREATE TABLE `link` (
                        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I'm new at springboot so please help.

the exceptions:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at com.example.spring_start.SpringStartApplication.main(SpringStartApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at com.example.spring_start.bootstrap.DatabaseLoader.addUsersAndRoles(DatabaseLoader.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.example.spring_start.bootstrap.DatabaseLoader.run(DatabaseLoader.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> ... 10 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3806) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 20 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'springit.role' doesn't exist
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you are going to need that table, either created by yourself or by Hibernate.

There is a config which you can add to spring boot apps using JPA in order to automatically generate the database schema (or the parts that are missing). Take a look here  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

in your entity class add the following

```html
@Entity(name="role")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).